# AwesomeWM - open/close window callback

Tags: awesome-wm

I have following idea:

I have a wallpaper in 2 version. One original and second a bit blurry. I want to change the wallpaper from original when first window/program opens on the screen. Once the last window/program is closed change the wallpaper back.
Also when I change between tags I want to check if any window/program is open or not and then adjust the wallpaper.

How can I do that?

P.S.
I use nitrogen to set wallpaper

[AwesomeWM client created/removed callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306126/awesomewm-client-created-removed-callback)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to set the wallpaper depending on the visible clients, but I have no idea how your Nitrogen calls look like. Just replace the `naughty.notify` lines with your Nitrogen invocations.

Somewhere in your `rc.lua`, you should find something like this:

```
awful.screen.connect_for_each_screen(function(s)
```

Add the following to that function

```
tag.connect_signal("property::selected", function(t)
  if #s.clients > 0 then
    naughty.notify({text = "set blurry wallpaper", timeout = 1})
  else
    naughty.notify({text = "set original wallpaper", timeout = 1})
  end
end
)
```

`table.getn` is deprecated but this is the solution for older lua versions:

```
tag.connect_signal("property::selected", function(t)
  if table.getn(s.clients) > 0 then
    naughty.notify({text = "set blurry wallpaper", timeout = 1})
  else
    naughty.notify({text = "set original wallpaper", timeout = 1})
  end
end
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting error tho: "attempt to call a nil value (field 'getn')". Also how about the "open first/close last" window callback?

Comment: Oh you are right. `table.getn` is deprecated. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on the final solution. Just a small question. Where did u get the "s" variable in the function and what exactly the "#" does?

Comment: `s` is the current screen when looping over all your screens ([here](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/screen.html#awful.screen.connect_for_each_screen) is the documentation). `#` is lua code, it's returning the number of array elements.